# C, Reading from txt file into struct

Tags: c

I am new in C Programming. I need to read data from file after first line and i need to put this contents into struct. I tried something but it didn't work. It reads the contents after 2nd line and it doesn't read strings. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
char *word; 
char *clue; 
int x; 
int y; 
char direction; 
int f; 
} Word_t;

Word_t* loadTextFile(FILE* myFile, int wNumbers){
    char line[100];
    Word_t *temp;
    temp = malloc(wNumbers*sizeof(Word_t));
    int i = 0;
    int j= 0;
    int status;

    while (status != EOF) {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof (line), myFile)) {
          status = fscanf(myFile,"%c %d %d %s %s", &temp[i].direction, &temp[i].x, &temp[i].y, temp[i].word, temp[i].clue);
          i++;
        }
    }   
}

int main(){
    Word_t *elements;
    char filename[256];
    FILE * fp;
    int rowCount, colCount, wordsCount;

    printf("Enter the name of text file:");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    fp = fopen(filename,"r");

    if(!fp)
    {
        fputs("fopen failed! Exiting...\n", stderr);
        exit(-1);
    }
    int status;
    status = fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d ", &rowCount, &colCount, &wordsCount);
    printf("Game is %d rows x %d cols with %d words\n", rowCount, colCount, wordsCount);
    elements = malloc(wordsCount*sizeof(Word_t));

    loadTextFile(fp, wordsCount);
}
```

Here is the sample file,

```
   5 5 7
   H 1 1 MILK White liquid produced by the mammals
   H 2 1 IN Used to indicate inclusion within space, a place, or limits
   H 3 3 BUS A road vehicle designed to carry many passengers
   H 5 3 DAN The name of a famous author whose surname is Brown
   V 1 1 MIND A set of cognitive faculties, e.g. consciousness, perception, etc.
   V 3 3 BAD Opposite of good
   V 2 5 ISBN International Standard Book Number
```

Comment: I see a few problems at first glance: 1) `while(status != EOF)` -- your variable `status` is not initialized on the first iteration of the while loop.  This is undefined behavior.  2) What are you doing with the `line` variable?  You are using `fscanf`. Did you mean to use `sscanf`.  3) `%s` reads a string, but your values `temp[i].word` and `temp[i].clue` are not initialized -- and don't point to allocated memory.  4) What is your function`loadTextFile` supposed to return?

Comment: I initialized status and I still have the same problem. I don't know how I can read content after first line using sscanf.

Comment: `i++;` is executed on the last  (failed) sscanf(), too. Just `break` out of a **for()** loop, and don't use the set-status-and-test-later uglyness.

Comment: learn to debug using your debugger. Step through the code, watch what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `status` is uninitialized, so you are using an un-initialized variable on the first iteration of `while (status != EOF)`.  I'd suggest initializing `status` to 0.

You are consuming a line of the file when you call `fgets`.  Once consumed you will be reading from the next line.  Instead of calling `fscanf` after your `fgets`, try using `sscanf`.  I also changed the last conversion specifier from `%s` to `%[^\n]s` so that it reads until reaching a newline.  This is because your `clue` string has spaces in it.

```
if (fgets(line, sizeof (line), myFile)) {
          status = sscanf(line,"%c %d %d %s %[^\n]s", &temp[i].direction, &temp[i].x, &temp[i].y, temp[i].word, temp[i].clue);
          i++;
}
```

The value `status` can be used to tell you how many input items were successfully read by `sscanf`

The `%s` argument to `sscanf` reads a string from input, but your values `temp[i].word` and `temp[i].clue` and uninitialized and do not point to allocated memory.  You need to allocate memory for these pointers first using `malloc`.

Your function `loadTextFile` does not returning anything.  Did you forget to return `temp`?

Also, you should probably return the number of valid items in your array so the caller knows how many items are available.  This can be accomplished by changing your method signature to accept a pointer to `wNumbers` instead of the value, and then resetting `*wNumbers` to the number of array elements populated.  You should also check inside your loop to make sure you don't read more elements than you allocate, and handle that case appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, I made the modification like you say but it doesn't read the all of the clue sentence. It just reads the first vocable of all the sentence.

Comment: Yeah.  This is because the `%s` specifier reads until finding a space.  Try `%[^\n]s` for the last format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below:-

```
elements = malloc(wordsCount*sizeof(Word_t));
```

You are not at all referring the above variable `elements` anywhere. Remove the above line of code.

Also you need to modify your below methods:-

```
 Word_t* loadTextFile(FILE* myFile, int wNumbers){
 char line[100];
 Word_t *temp;
 temp = (Word_t *) malloc(wNumbers * sizeof(Word_t));
 int i = 0;
 int j= 0;
 int status;

 while (true) {
    if (fgets(line, sizeof (line), myFile)) {
      //you need to allocate proper memory for below two variables
      temp[i].word = malloc(10); 
      temp[i].clue = malloc(60);//you need to check how much memory your need for this variable
      status = fscanf(myFile,"%c %d %d %s %s", &temp[i].direction, &temp[i].x, &temp[i].y, temp[i].word, temp[i].clue);
      i++;
     }
      else{
           break;//end of file
      }
  }   
}
```